# How can I encode this mysql result with json_encode? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
//this is my mysql result
$search_result=$this->Connect_user_model->get_user($key_word);
$info=array();

foreach($search_result as $row){
    $info[]=array('username' => $row->username, 
                  'email' => $row->email, 
                  'gender' => $row->gender);
    echo json_encode($info);'
}
```

how can i loop this response?
i get responce like--

```
0: {
    username: iamanam,
    email: 1,
    gender: Male
}
email: "1"
gender: "Male"
username: "iamanam"
1: {
    username: admin,
    email: iamanam3@gmail.com,
    gender: Male
}
email: "iamanam3@gmail.com"
gender: "Male"
username: "admin"
2: {
    username: iamanam,
    email: 1@1.com,
    gender: Male
}
email: "1@1.com"
gender: "Male"
username: "iamanam"
```

when i echo json_encode outside loop.it works but i got each result double
i use this function for loop ----

```
function process_response(data){
    var show_user='';

     $.each(data,function(contact,contactInfo) {

      show_user+='<div class="discounted-item '+contactInfo.gender+' music-playlist">';
      show_user+='<img src="" alt="" class="music-playlist-left" width="38px" height="38px"  />';
      show_user+='<h1>';
      show_user+=contactInfo.username;
      show_user+='</h1>';
      show_user+='<p>';
      show_user+= contactInfo.gender;
      show_user+='</p>';
      show_user+='<a  href="" title="" class="tips" rel="">';
      show_user+='<img src="" alt="f" class="music-playlist-right" id="img"></a>';
      show_user+='</div>';

     }); // end of each()

     // add finished HTML to page
     $('#info').append(show_user);

}//process_responce
```

Comment: What is actually happening? Do you get an error?

Comment: What is actually contained in `$search_result`?  What is your expected output?  What is actually output?  What is your actual question?

Comment: shouldn't it be out side the foreach loop ?

Comment: You are outputting multiple JSON strings, you must send exactly one JSON string

Comment: i got bunch of array like this- 0: {
    username: iamanam,
    email: 1,
    gender: Male
}
email: "1"
gender: "Male"
username: "iamanam"
1: {
    username: admin,
    email: iamanam3@gmail.com,
    gender: Male
}
email: "iamanam3@gmail.com"
gender: "Male"
username: "admin"
2: {
    username: iamanam,
    email: 1@1.com,
    gender: Male
}
email: "1@1.com"
gender: "Male"
username: "iamanam"
3: {
    username: abul,
    email: ,
    gender: Male
}
email: ""
gender: "Male"
username: "abul"

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually mean the echo out the JSON string each time you iterate through the  results?  If you move the echo statement out of the for loop you'll get one JSON object with all of your data, rather than getting the JSON object each time data is added.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing wrong is outputting the JSON in a loop.

This means that your output is actually several separate JSON blocks:  If you're trying to read that output as a single JSON block, it won't work.

What you need to do is build it all into an array, and output the JSON after you've finished looping the array.

Since you're already building the `$info[]` array correctly, all you need to do to fix your code it move the `echo` outside the `foreach` loop, as follows:

```
foreach($search_result as $row){
    $info[]=array('username' => $row->username, 
                  'email' => $row->email, 
                  'gender' => $row->gender);
}
echo json_encode($info);
```

Hope that helps.

By the way, if `$row` contains only those three fields, it's worth knowing that `json_encode()` is capable of encoding an object just as easily as an array. So if `$row` is just those three fields, then you could simply do `$info[]=$row;` inside the loop, and the output at the end will be the same.

Comment: when i echo outside the loop.it works but when  i loop the result using each(jquery) function i got each result double..

Comment: well, at least we've solved one problem. I'd suggest asking the jQuery part as a separate question, because it's a separate issue.